# VBS file to start bat.file

Tags: vbscript

I was able to opened my gmail but tried to open next url a. Can I do that? How?

Need to fix right one ( WshShell.Exec "C:\test.bat" )

```
'Script starts here
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Wait 1 second (1000 ms)
WScript.Sleep 1000

'Open IE and go to gmail.com (your IExplore.exe file location may be different)
WshShell.Exec "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE gmail.com"

'Allow time for IE to finish loading (about 15 secs for slow connections/machines)
WScript.Sleep 10000

'Send the login info in the login box
'login (change username to your login name
WshShell.Sendkeys "xxxxxxxxxx"
WScript.Sleep 500

'hit TAB key to move to password field
WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 500

'Send the password info
'change your password to your login password
WshShell.Sendkeys "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
WScript.Sleep 500

'Hit 'Enter' key to log-in
WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 10000

WshShell.Exec "C:\test.bat"

'Allow time for IE to finish loading (about 15 secs for slow connections/machines)
WScript.Sleep 15000

'Send the login info in the login box
'login (change username to your login name
WshShell.Sendkeys "xxxxxxxxx"
WScript.Sleep 500

'hit TAB key to move to password field
WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 500

'Send the password info
'change your password to your login password
WshShell.Sendkeys "xxxxxxxx"
WScript.Sleep 500

'Hit 'Enter' key to log-in
WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: You would be much better off scripting IE directly.  It has its own automation object.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This worked for me.

test.vbs

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Exec "test.bat"
```

and test.bat

```
@echo off 
start www.yahoo.com
```

Comment: it did execute cmd.exe but not open the other url. i put start http://yahoo.com on bat file. VBS file seems works but not bat.file

Comment: Edited with a working example - does that work for you? If so then add to the files until they fail.

Comment: Is there a way to add to open IE tab for other url from VBS file?